# Jetpack Compose pass parameter to viewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

How can we pass parameter to `viewModel` in `Jetpack Compose`?

This is my composable

```
    @Composable
    fun UsersList() {
      val myViewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel("db2name") // pass param like this
    }
```

This is `viewModel`

```
    class MyViewModel(private val dbname) : ViewModel() {
        private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
            MutableLiveData<List<User>>().also {
                loadUsers()
            }
        }
    
        fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
            return users
        }
    
        private fun loadUsers() {
            // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

you need to create a factory to pass dynamic parameter to ViewModel like this:

```
class MyViewModelFactory(private val dbname: String) :
    ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = MyViewModel(dbname) as T
}
```

then use your factory like this in composable functions:

```
@Composable
fun UsersList() {
    val myViewModel: MyViewModel =
        viewModel(factory = MyViewModelFactory("db2name")) // pass param like this
}
```

and now you have access to dbname parameter in your ViewModel:

```
class MyViewModel(private val dbname:String) : ViewModel() {
    // ...rest of the viewModel logics here
}
```

Comment: why this not documented in android website?

Comment: This is actually pretty tough to find. If you play with the `DataStore` Preferences codelabs, of which there are two, one of them  (*Working with Preferences DataStore*, **not** *Preferences DataStore*) has an end solution that does make use of this implementation in tying a `UserRespository` class to a `ViewModel` but the codelab itself doesn't teach you anything about it and full of discrepencies (codelab not repo). I guess we're expected to know this from the Android View side as its strongly recommended in the View system to **always** use `ViewModelProvider` to manage ViewModel instances.

Comment: Thanks for this, I created multiple activities in my app assuming its not possible to call viewModel Factory classes in composable functions....

Answer (score 20):

If you use Navigation component, you get this for free in `SavedStateHandle` for view model.

Pass the argument to the composable that calls the view model and retrieve it with the same name on view model from saved state handle.

Like this:

On NavHost:

```
NavHost(
(...)
    composable(
            route = [route string like this $[route]/{$[argument name]}],
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument([argument name]) { type = NavType.[type: Int/String/Boolean/etc.] }
            )
        ) {
            // access your viewModel in your composable
            val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()
        }
    )
)
```

On view model:

```
class ViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) {

    private val argument = checkNotNull(savedStateHandle.get<[type]>([argument name]))
}
```

Your argument will magically appear without having a view model factory.

Comment: Best answer, thank you! [Pro Android Dev article to explain](https://proandroiddev.com/passing-safe-args-to-your-viewmodel-with-hilt-366762ff3f57)

Answer (score 10):

The other solutions work, but you have to create a factory for each ViewModel which seems overkill.

The more universal solution is like this:

```
inline fun <VM : ViewModel> viewModelFactory(crossinline f: () -> VM) =
    object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(aClass: Class<T>):T = f() as T
    }
```

And use it like this:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(factory = viewModelFactory {
        MyViewModel("Test Name")
    })
}
```

For ViewModel like this:

```
class MyViewModel(
  val name: String
):ViewModel() {}
```

Comment: An Android app without at least three Unchecked Cast is considered a dull app.

Answer (score 4):

With latest library androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2
is simple as this:

```
val myViewModel = viewModel {
  MyViewModel(param)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually there is no common case where you need to do this. In android MVVM viewmodels get their data from repositories through dependency injection.

Here is the official documentation to the recommended android architecture: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide#recommended-app-arch

Comment: This is actually great, but I think that its also an overload for any small application. I believe a common case for doing what this question asks is for any small app. I think it'll only abstract beginners away from a wealth of understanding too in relieving them from understanding how to manage a small set of dependencies, etc.

However, I do agree 100% that this is the way to go in any moderately-sized application, or when you've decided for yourself to implement this architecture in a one-all template you use for anything; good for small apps in such a case too.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need anymore to create the `viewModelFactory` by ourselves.

Now it is included inside `androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel`

```
/**
 * Creates an [InitializerViewModelFactory] with the initializers provided in the builder.
 */
public inline fun viewModelFactory(
    builder: InitializerViewModelFactoryBuilder.() -> Unit
): ViewModelProvider.Factory = InitializerViewModelFactoryBuilder().apply(builder).build()
```

And can be used as

```
 val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(factory = viewModelFactory {
    initializer {
            MyViewModel(AuthRepoImpl(apiService), HomeRepoImpl(apiService))
    }
 })
```

Comment: the usage example isn't valid though. you have to call addInitializer() on context receiver in the lambda

Comment: @deviant I updated the example code to have the initializer block wrapping the constructor.  This should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some Jetpack Compose/Kotlin-specific syntax for implementing the same:

*ui/settings/SettingsViewModel.kt*

```kotlin
class SettingsViewModel(
    private val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    /* Your implementation */
}

class SettingsViewModelFactory(
    private val settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create( modelClass: Class<T> ): T {
        if( modelClass.isAssignableFrom( SettingsViewModel::class.java ) ) {
            @Suppress( "UNCHECKED_CAST" )
            return SettingsViewModel( settingsRepository ) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException( "Unknown ViewModel Class" )
    }    

}
```

Then:

*MainActivity.kt*

```kotlin
/* dataStore by preferencesDataStore */

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
    
    // Here we instantiate our ViewModel leveraging delegates and
    // a trailing lambda
    private val settingsViewModel by viewModels<SettingsViewModel> {
        SettingsViewModelFactory(
            settingsRepository
        )
    }

    /* onCreate -> setContent -> etc */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned by @Secret Keeper you need to create factory.

> If your ViewModel has dependencies, viewModel() takes an optional
> ViewModelProvider.Factory as a parameter.

```
class MyViewModelFactory(
    private val dbname: String
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyViewModel::class.java)) {
            return MyViewModel(dbname) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

To create your viewModel you will pass optional parameter. Inside your Composable you can do something like this.

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel(
factory = MyViewModelFactory(
    dbname = "myDbName"
)
```