# How to pass parameter to viewmodel constructor using HiltViewModel library with jetpack compose

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

How to pass parameter to viewmodel constructor using HiltViewModel library with jetpack compose
My code:

```
@HiltViewModel
class GetPurchaseViewModel @Inject constructor(val id:Long) : ViewModel() {
    private val service= RestModule
    var state = MutableStateFlow<State>(State.START)

    init{
        get(id)
    }

    private fun get(id:Long){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            state.value = State.LOADING
            try {
                val users = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

                    service.getIntance().getPurchase(id)
                }

                state.value = State.SUCCESLISTPURCHASE(users)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                state.value = State.FAILURE(message = e.localizedMessage!!)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

my call in my composable function :

```
val model:GetPurchaseViewModel=hiltViewModel(idUser)
```

Comment: Depending on where that id comes from, you could use the savedStateHandle in the viewmodel, it gets pre-populated with the navigation arguments if you use the navigation artifact.

Comment: do you have any easy examples of doing this? or some site that explains

Comment: I just put together a quick sample here: https://github.com/fvilarino/Navigation-Sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass id and application to a viewModel/viewModelFactory in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69145407/how-to-pass-id-and-application-to-a-viewmodel-viewmodelfactory-in-jetpack-compos)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Hilt to inject a safe-args argument into a viewmodel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350331/how-to-use-hilt-to-inject-a-safe-args-argument-into-a-viewmodel)

Comment: The short answer is if you place the arg in a NavHost argument, it will auto-magically pass to the SavedStateHandle - [see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73269361/1703677)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `@AssistedInject`, [here is official documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html)

Also please take a look at this issue
[[AssistedInject] Integration with @HiltViewModel #2287](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287)