# My ViewModel is being recomposed on changing a mutablestate values

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

LoginScreen() is my composable function and i am trying to use a textfield inside it which takes email data from my viewmodel.Everytime my email values changes, LoginScreen function is recomposed and reinitialises my viewModel which results in no change in my textfield.
I am wondering why is this happening and how to fix it.

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(navController: NavHostController
){

    var viewModel=LoginScreenViewModel(navController = navController, LocalContext.current)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(primary)
            .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
    ){
        TextField(value = viewModel.emailText
            , onValueChange = {
                viewModel.emailText=it
                Log.i("Email text",viewModel.emailText)
            },
            placeholder = {
                Text("Email")
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 10.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

```
class LoginScreenViewModel():ViewModel() {
    var emailText by mutableStateOf("a")
    var passwordText by mutableStateOf("")
    var isVisibilityOn by mutableStateOf(false)

    lateinit var mAuth:FirebaseAuth

    private lateinit var navController: NavHostController
    private lateinit var context: Context

    constructor(navController: NavHostController,context:Context) : this() {
        this.navController=navController
        this.context=context
    }
}
```

Comment: Use viewModel function to obtain an instance of your viewmodel inside composables. You need to create a factory to pass parameters to viewmodel. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67982296/17787605

Comment: Follow view model [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel)

Answer (score 1):

> var viewModel=LoginScreenViewModel(navController = navController, LocalContext.current)

Well, because you are not using `val viewModel = remember { ViewModelProvider(LocalViewModelStore.current, object: ViewModelProvider.Factory { override fun <T: ViewModel> create(clazz: Class<T>) = LoginScreenViewModel(navController) } }).get(LoginScreenViewModel::class.java) }` to get the reference to your ViewModel.

Although you can greatly reduce that with [just calling `= viewModel(factory = /* factory */)`.](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:lifecycle/lifecycle-viewmodel-compose/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/ViewModel.kt;l=49?q=fun%20viewmodel)

Then again, you can't directly pass a `NavController` reference to a `ViewModel`, you'd need to use a channel and a DisposableEffect/LaunchedEffect to send commands from ViewModel to a NavController.